# How to update the app every 24 hours in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I want to update my local database with current server through web service. I know how to send a request to the server and parse the web service output. The problem is, i want this update to happen every 24 hours irrespective of whether the app is opened or closed. I just want to know whether it can be done or not. If possible can anyone tell me how to do this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this as of iOS 6.x (but check the dev forums for some relevant info about iOS 7).

Comment: You can use push-notification for it.

Comment: What sort of data you're trying to push to the server?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen It is just a XML output.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any advantage to this approach to updating. Why not have the app check time since last update and update if t > 24hr.? Saves server load and device battery.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done only when your app is open(Foreground) using `UILocalNotifications` which can be used to fire an event after a duration and you can update your database.

But if app is not opened you can not perform changes in database. because apple doesn't allow to make changes in database when application is inactive.

Check this link : [Which type of services can be used if app is in background mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211)

Comment: even the same answer is also in my mind n before typing the ans i have just read yours. :)

Answer (score 2):

- Create a column for timestamp in your `webservice` DB.
- On first launch inside 
  `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` method in `appDelegate`, get the `timestamp` from server and save that in you local `DB/Plist` etc.
- Put a condition in `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` and when application comes to foreground again, check if the `local timestamp` and `server timestamp` has a difference of `24 hours`, start updating the `local DB` with the `server`. And after the update is done, again save `timestamp` from `server` to `local` for next 24 hours.

Makes sense? Update will start only when `application` comes to `foreGround`. Through this way you can update your `local DB` not only on 24 hours but anytime you want.

The other simple way is to create a `file` (any empty file) locally when `application` comes to `foreground`. And when `application` comes to `foreGround` next time, check whether `creation time` of this file is more than 24 hours. If yes, grab data from server and re-write the `file`. In this way you can not send a signal from server to update the local app DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in background because apple does not allow this.

you can do this when your app is open.

When you update your database first time, you can save your timestamp in NSUserDefaults and then next time when your app is open check current timestamp is greater than (24 hours) of your previous timestamp (that is stored in NSUserDefaults) then update your database and update the timestamp in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Apple won't allow it.

It should be done as a best-effort to try to keep updated, there's no sure-fire way that the user will download your stuff, that the app will be kept in foreground, that his 3G coverage is good (looking at you, T-Mobile), etc.

If you're dealing with static content that should be updated once in a while, then keep the last date you updated in the device (`NSUserDefaults` comes to mind), and when the user launches the app, ask the server "Hey bro, last time I updated was this `NSDate`, do you got anything for me?" And then perform the update accordingly.