# Apple push notification-like service, only when running in foreground

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, foreground

I have an iOS app that needs to update its content while running in foreground automatically. My app does NOT need to update if in background.

There is a existing way to do so, which is APNS(Apple Push Notification Service). 
Because I don't want users to see notification message while in background, using push notification without alert or message might be a solution.

However, if using APNS, iOS would ask users to confirm if they want to receive notifications by my app. I think that users may be confused when being asked by the OS since my app does not actually push notification to users.

The current method I use is keep pulling my API every 30 seconds to see if new content is available. This method would fail if there are too many users.

Is there any 3rd party push-notification-like service that provides notification while app runs in foreground only? (no need to get notification while in background)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Silent notification for that, in this 
In the WWDC 2013's "What's New with Multitasking" presentation, there is a section about Silent Push Notifications. if you send the APS payload with just the **content-available set to 1**, users will not be notified of the notification.

And the notification arrives in **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler**:

Your payload is like

```
{ 
  aps: {
          content-available: 1,
          sound: "default"
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When registering notification for the first time(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:), iOS asks user to confirm that. However, users may be confused because I do not send notification message to them.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `push notification`, it is necessary for user to accept `push notification` on application 1st run. You can set a `silent push notification` also and for this user will not get any alert of getting a `notification` during `application run loop`.

If you want to avoid `push notification`, then you can only set a `NSTimer` that you are doing already.

There can be a 3rd case, Application only sync with the server when it comes to `foreground`. And for this you can refer to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17740322/362310) post.

Comment: I think the best solution is to show a short description to tell users that turning on push notification enables automatically content update.

Comment: may be, but show this alert after a user presses `NO` on the push notification alert.